# Combining/integrating 2 Solutions on Visual Studio for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I need to automate a measuring procedure so there is a sensor and moving stage. Each equipment comes with its own sample code and thus its own solution in Visual Studio. I edited the code over the sample code itself.

So how do I combine/integrate both of solution together?

I tried to copy paste the code from 1 solution to another on the source file and added the directory of the header file, and dll but got this error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

For a few of the functions I copied over from the other source file.

Comment: Since you have two different sets of source code, the approach I would take is to have each as a project in its own separate folder hierarchy and to then add each of the projects to a single solution. Each project would generate a library which would then be added to your main which would be in a third folder hierarchy. So create a new VS solution with your main. Next add to that solution two new projects. Then add to each of the projects the source code for that project library. Without more details about how the source is organized it is hard to give you specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- Identify exactly which symbols are unresolved - this should be clearly stated in the error messages, although there may be some name mangling to interpret.
- Identify where, in the original projects, the linker was finding those definitions. Was it in project souce code? Was it in third-party libraries? Was it somewhere else?
- Ensure that all of those are included in the link dependencies for the combined project.